# Adding tabs Custom Object which are Undeleted

Tags: custom, tab

I created a custom Object and while creating I forgot toopt "Launch New Custom Tab Wizard after saving this custom object ".
So I was unable to add a tab to that object later, which made me to delete that object and create another with selecting launch new custom tab option.
My question, is there any way I can add a tab to that object and use it in my app?
And yes, it was in Deployed mode only.

Question 2:

I deleted an object. Since we have a option in SFDC that we can undelete before 15 days 
I undeleted the object. But now same problem as 1st question. I cannot locate my object, even if I do also I am unable to add a tab to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create Tabs to custom objects.

1. Go to Setup | Create | Tabs
2. Click New
3. Go through the wizard, selecting the object, icon, and profile settings

Note: If a tab is Hidden, those users will not be able to use it nor search its objects.

For more details, see [Creating Custom Object Tabs](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_custom_object_tabs.htm).